# How to unhide friending activity in recent activity on Facebook wall? (says I have no stories hidden)

Tags: facebook

My recent activity doesn't show the part that says I am now friends with somebody. How do I get it back? I have already tried going to options at the bottom of my wall.

For most people, if you go on to your wall, scroll right down to the bottom of your page and click on "Edit options" on the right hand side, a box should open saying "Edit your profile story settings" and you just click the x beside friending activity. The problem I'm having is that it says I have no stories hidden.

Comment: do you have the Timeline profile or still the old one?

Comment: the old one still

Comment: Have you hidden your friend list from your friends? If yes, then set the privacy setting of your friend list to `Friends` and the activity should start showing up on your profile once again.

Comment: What about if u had the timeline how would u do it then

Answer (score 2):

Go to your ***activity log***. At the top it will say ***posts and apps***, switch to ***all***. Now you will literally be able to see everything you did, including the things you searched for on Facebook and the profiles you viewed. You will also find friending activity you hid, so you can *unhide*.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to your Timeline.
2. Click: **Activity Log** → **Posts and Apps** → **Friends**.
3. You can see: **Friend activity can show up in** — Click the settings icon next to this, then check: **Recent Activity**

Answer (score -2):

had the same problem, just managed to solve it. This is what you do.
Go on your Profile,
click on Activity Log.
in the long list on the left hand side under Photos, Likes, Comments there's an option to expand to get the rest of the list by clicking on MORE.
Once it's done that, find the option that says FRIENDS. A page will load, next to where it says 'who can see your friends list' there is a symbol that looks like a left pointing arrow (really hard symbol to have to try to describe!). It'll open up a dialog box with 4 options to tick/untick. One of them is Recent activity. Hey presto, your friending activity is once again visible on your Profile page. :)